# Upload IOS APP to appstore without distribution provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

In our company, we are developing cordova hybrid IOS apps for an inmportant client. In UAT, we distribute the apps using testflight in itunes connect. But in Production, they do the job. We send them the IOS cordova project and they use Xcode and put their profiles for distribution.

We are automating all the process. UAT is completed but PRO is still pending because they don't want us to handle their provisioning profiles for distribution in prod. Is there any way to upload the IPA to their itunes connect and just let them to sign in some way? Maybe they can create customized developer provisioning profiles for us?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you could archive (release configuration), send them the archive (_not the project_) and they could import the archive to Xcode, re-sign (as part of the upload process) and upload to the appstore. All this, provided that the bundle id is under their account...

Comment: but that means they need to still using xcode :/ I know that when we are archiving we are signing but I guess in case we cannot set the original mobile provision (they want us to restrict its access for security reasons) How about set up as automate aquisition? Is the application signed before uploading?